# Redirecting to Edit Page in Razor Pages CRUD Operation (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have created a CRUD operation demo using Razor Pages in C#. Each action is implemented on a different page, and now I'm looking to redirect to an edit page to modify data. How can I perform a method call for editing data and redirect to the edit page in a Razor Pages application?

```
<form method="get">
    <span class="btn-group pull-right" style="margin-top: 5px">
        <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" asp-page="\Book\Edit" asp-route-id="@item.BookID" style="background-color: green; height: 29px; margin-top: -1px;"> 
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
        </a>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" asp-page-handler="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.BookID" style="height: 27px; margin-top: 0px;"                                                        onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this Book?');">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you want  to use `return RedirectToPage("./Edit");` ?  Where do you perform a method call for editing ?

Comment: return RedirectToPage("./Edit"); it's not working also

Comment: Are you passing the Id to the edit page which need to be edited?

Comment: For Edit page redirection you should try like this ` return RedirectToPage("./Edit", new { id = id });` because edit page need to pass the id usually.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I perform a method call for editing data and redirect to the
> edit page in a Razor Pages application?

If your edit page has a `PageHandlerConstraint` attribute, include it in the route value in order to redirect to the page.

Let' say, you have razor edit page which accept a Id parameter while loading. If you want to load with a specific Id then the Edit page whould be shown as following:

[image]

On load it would invoke `OnGetAsync` method. After your modification you would submit to `OnPostAsync` for update the database. Now if you would like to redirect to the edit page again, you would need to pass the edit page handler constrains name along with the value which is the ID.

You can do like this `RedirectToPage("EditExample", new { pageHandler = "EditExample", id = 101 });`

Let's have a look in practice, how we can achieve that:

Razor page Class:

```
public class EditExampleModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;

    public EditExampleModel(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public Product Product { get; set; }


    public async Task OnGetAsync(int Id)
    {
        List<Product> _listOfProduts = new List<Product>()
                        {
                            new Product() { Id =101, Name ="RAM", Price= 163},
                            new Product() { Id =102, Name ="Hard Disk", Price= 900},
                            new Product() { Id =103, Name ="Motherboad", Price= 1800},
                            new Product() { Id =104, Name ="CPU",Price= 1500 },
                        };


        Product = _listOfProduts.Where(product => product.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public async Task<RedirectToPageResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToPage();
        }

        // _dbContext.Products.Update(Product);
        //  await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
       
        Id = 101;
        return RedirectToPage("EditExample", new { pageHandler = "EditExample", id = 101 });
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@page
@model EditExampleModel


<h1>Edit Product</h1>

<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="Id" type="hidden" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Name">Name:</label>
        <input asp-for="Product.Name" class="form-control" id="Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Price">Price:</label>
        <input asp-for="Product.Price" type="number" class="form-control" id="Price" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#the-editcshtml-file) for few other implementaion example.